# Sympy summation with indexed variable

Tags: sum, sympy, calculus

I try to create a sympy expression with a Sum with an indexed variable as previous explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24834447/how-to-create-an-indexed-variable-in-sympy)
However, I can not do lambdify of this expression and give an array to get the sum calculated.
Is this impossible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps like this?

```py
s = Sum(Indexed('x',i),(i,1,3))
f = lambda x: Subs(s.doit(), [s.function.subs(s.variables[0], j)
for j in range(s.limits[0][1], s.limits[0][2] + 1)], x).doit()

>>> f((30,10,2))
42
```

Comment: Thanks!! Although your solution works perfectly fine, for completion sake, what I was looking for was not exactly that. In your example you limit the sum from 1 to 3, while I want to have from 0 to n (basically for an array with variable size). I think I know now how to do it but I don´t know how to correctly add code to a comment!

Comment: Would be nice to add some explanation since it's not straightforward (s.limits is not mentioned in Sum doc). I've just started using sympy; it seems to me that the [s.function.subs(s.variables[0], j)
... for j in range(s.limits[0][1], s.limits[0][2] + 1)] replace Indexed elements with their equivalent integer and only then substitute. this step seems mandatory.

Comment: I'd upvote another post with the same solution but where the code can be copy-pasted more easily.

Comment: code is updated

Answer (score 5):

You can use lambdify. Just make sure the limits of the sum match the iterables of a numpy array.

```
from sympy import Sum, symbols, Indexed, lambdify
import numpy as np

x, i = symbols("x i")
s = Sum(Indexed('x',i),(i,0,3))
f = lambdify(x, s)
b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
f(b)
```