# Can I do this kind of simplification in symbol computation?

Tags: python, sympy

Can I simplify the sum of a series like this using SymPy or other software?

I can simplify the sum of such series `{i}`:

```
summation(i, (i, 1, n))
```

I don't know how to deal with the series with subscripts `{a_i}`

```
a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4 = symbols("a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4")
```

Say, I have a equation `a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_100 - x = 0`. The answer will be :
`x = a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_100`. 
It is too long. I want to make it shorter with some other symbols `i` and functions `summation`, like `x = summation(a_i, (i, 1, 100 ))`.

The code `Sum(Indexed("x", i), (i, 1, 4)).doit()` will get the result `x[1] + x[2] + x[3] + x[4]`. However, I want to reverse the process. I want the code `somefunction(x[1]+x[2]+x[3]+x[4])` to get the result `Sum(Index("x", i), (i, 1, 4))`.

Comment: Is your question to detect that you input a series and output the closed form expression? My math terminology might be off. But I think the answers below don't answer your question in that case.

Comment: Yes, I just want to make the expression shorter.

Comment: http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.1/modules/simplify/simplify.html Answer might be there. Never did this myself.

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking.  If you show what you have tried it might help clarify the question.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402387/sympy-summation-with-indexed-variable.  (I think you are clouding the issue by tagging a bunch of other languages, btw)

Comment: ok, now its clear..!  I can tell you in mathematica there probably is some round about way to do that but it is *not trivial*

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with reflection:

```
local = locals()
sum(local['a_' + i] for i in range(1, n + 1))
```

Comment: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'Symbol' objects ?

Comment: I try your answer. `sum(local['a_' + i] for i in range(1, n + 1))`. TypeError: <class 'sympy.core.add.Add'> is not a number. What module you answer use? I can't make it work.

Comment: @FangquanShi, this is just vanilla python. As others have said it is not clear what you are asking. Can you edit your question and explain where you are getting the `a_1, a_2, ..., a_n` symbols from, what they represent, and what you want to do with them?

Answer (score 0):

mathemetica solution (mostly to show how painful this is )

```
 pp[list_] /; Length@Union[Head /@ list] > 1 :=
      Total[ pp /@ GatherBy[list, Head] ]
 pp[list_] /; 
     Length@list > 1 && (Sort[Flatten[List @@ # & /@ list ]] == 
         (rg = Range[list[[1, 1]], list[[-1, 1]]])) :=
           sum[Head[list[[1]]][i], {i, rg[[1]], rg[[2]]}]
 pp[list_] := Plus @@ list


 (a[1] + a[2] + q[3] + 2)/(b[1] + b[2] + c[3] + b[3] + c[4]) /. 
       x_Plus :> (pp@(List @@ x))
```

> [image]

note the lowercase `s` on `sum` (which is not a defined function) because mathematical will automatically expand out `Sum` as soon as you use it. We can recover the original with

```
 %/. sum->Sum

 (2 + a[1] + a[2] + q[3])/(b[1] + b[2] + c[3] + c[4])
```

Comment: Thank you. It is fairly complicated.